# How to convert a string consisting of two json elements for processing by a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, sorting

I get through ajax a string consisting of two elements that I can't separate from each other.

```
{"0":"04.14.23","date":"04.14.23","1":"nixanosize","login":"nixanosize","2":"xori","name_company":"xori","3":"qqqq","name":"qqqq","4":"","inn":"","5":"","info":"","6":"","boss":"","7":"","street":"","8":"","number":"","9":"","comment_company":""}
{"0":"04.14.23","date":"04.14.23","1":"nixanosize","login":"nixanosize","2":"xori","name_company":"xori","3":"","name":"","4":"","inn":"","5":"2day","info":"2day","6":"","boss":"","7":"","street":"","8":"","number":"","9":"","comment_company":""}
```

Help me remove duplicate elements and move this string to an array with two attachments, so that after I can go through the while loop and take the necessary data.

In short, I can't process this line correctly.

```
[["date":"04.14.23","login":"nixanosize","name_company":"xori","name":"qqqq","inn":"","info":"","boss":"","street":"","number":"","comment_company":""],
["date":"04.14.23","login":"nixanosize","name_company":"xori","name":"qqqq","inn":"","info":"","boss":"","street":"","number":"","comment_company":""]]
```

This is an approximate view of what I would like to come to.

Nevertheless, it would be nice to hear your suggestions.

I tried to use regular expressions and .split(), but in my hands it did not give the desired result.

Comment: and the winning programming language here is?

Comment: in this case I need to convert this using native js

Comment: analyzing the problem, I came to the conclusion that I should try try to modify my PHP script to push all that objects into array and then return that array as output to get result

Comment: Both strings are valid `JSON`, but yes, if you are in control of the backend then by all means pass a valid array.

Comment: $array[] = $row;
echo json_encode($array);

this solved part of the problem and now I get a valid array.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the question was originally posed incorrectly. Instead of changing the resulting string, I tried to change the output.

In this case, I get the correct JSON data that I can use. It was worth changing the PhP script, and not torturing yourself and js.

`$array[] = $row;  echo json_encode($array);`

Upadate:

`$array = array($row['date'],$row['login'],$row['name_company']); echo json_encode($array);`

This decision prompted me @pilchard

Answer (score 0):

As you want to remove a duplicate properties from an object and as per the object structure you mentioned in the post. I can see that we have a numeric key for each duplicated property. So what we can do is that we can remove those numeric key properties from an object with the help of regex [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method and then push that into an array.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const str = '{"0":"04.14.23","date":"04.14.23","1":"nixanosize","login":"nixanosize","2":"xori","name_company":"xori","3":"qqqq","name":"qqqq","4":"","inn":"","5":"","info":"","6":"","boss":"","7":"","street":"","8":"","number":"","9":"","comment_company":""}';

const jsonObj = JSON.parse(str);

const arr = [];

Object.keys(jsonObj).forEach(key => {
    if (key.match(/^[0-9]+$/)?.length) {
    delete jsonObj[key]
  }
});

arr.push(jsonObj);

console.log(arr);
```

***Note :*** The output you are expecting is not a valid JSON, It should be an `array of objects` instead of `array of arrays`.